# Is there a better way to do type checking when a message is recived over a tcp socket?

Tags: c#, types, typechecking

At first i was just doing if statements to check the type of the object sent but if you have a bunch of different types of message objects then that can be a real pain.  Then i thought and i made a event that is called then each function that does something when a certain type is listening for that event and when its called it checks it.

the way with the if statements

```
   //code for after message received - if you need the code for listening for the message i can give it but i don't see a need
   Type msgType = msgObj.getType();
   if(msgType == messageType1){
        //do stuff
   }
   else if(msgType == messageType2){
        //do more stuff
    }
   // and so on
```

as you can see this can suck if you have alot of differnt types of messages

the way with the event

```
   private delegate messageEvent(object message);
   public event messageEvent onMessage;

   //code after message received
   onMessage(msgObj);


   // sample function that will listen for the onMessage event
   private void onMessage(object message){
        if(message.getType() == typeForThisFunction){
              //do somthing
        }
   }
```

as you can see this is a little easier than the if statements but still can be a pain to make sure everything is listening and also see a problem if there is alot of differnt types of messages and having them all check at the same time.

is there a better way of doing this thats alot easier?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a commonly used method that is not only more convenient, but can also be configured at runtime (while the `if`/`else` or an equivalent `switch` can only be configured at compile time): make a `Dictionary`.

```
var dict = new Dictionary<Type, Action<object>>
           {
               { typeof(SomeMessage), m => this.Process((SomeMessage)m) },
               { typeof(OtherMessage), m => this.Process((OtherMessage)m) },
           };
```

The values in the dictionary are just for an example, you could choose to do things differently according to your requirements.

Other approaches similar to your event-based method are also valid as well. For example, you could have your business logic keep a collection of objects of classes like these:

```
 interface IMessageProcessor
 {
     bool WantsToHandle(MessageBaseClass message);
 }

 class SomeMessageProcessor : IMessageProcessor { /* ...*/ }
 class OtherMessageProcessor : IMessageProcessor { /* ...*/ }
```

`MessageBaseClass` is supposed to contain information on the "type" of the message; of course you could just pass `object` and filter on the runtime type of the object, but that would be slower. When a message arrives, you offer it to each `IMessageProcessor` in turn.

Comment: can you explain the first one a little more? i haven't ever used Dictionary before.  it looks like your adding a the process that should be called for each type into a dictionary and using the type as the key. what do you do after that?

Comment: @Shredder2500: You get a message and do `.GetType()` on it; use the result to check if such a key exists; if it does, get the corresponding value (which is a function) and call it, passing the message as a parameter. You should refer to MSDN for more information on how to use a dictionary.